# The name does not exist in the current context Unity script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm missing something important here but I can't figure out what it is.

I have a camera object with a script attached to it (NoiseAndGrain.cs)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EventHandler : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject cameraLeft;
    public GameObject cameraRight;

    void Start () {   
        if (GlobalVariables.grainON == false) {
            cameraLeft.GetComponent<NoiseAndGrain>.enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

I'm reading the camera object and I'm able to call everything attached to it (GUI Layer, Transform, Flare layer and so on)
except the cs scripts.
For example

```
cameraLeft.GetComponent<GUILayer>.enabled = false;
```

works perfectly.

All these scripts are in the Standard Assets directory and I don't understand what's going on.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you specify which line and identifier is said not to exist in scope? You're referring to a number of things that could be the culprit...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it was terribly stupid.

I wasn't using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;

By the way, the line that was returning the error was

```
cameraLeft.GetComponent<NoiseAndGrain>.enabled = false;
```

When hovering the mouse over NoiseAndGrain (marked in red), i would get this error

The name NoiseAndGrain does not exist in the current context